# Sharing Bluetooth pairing information (for a mesh network)

Tags: language-agnostic, bluetooth, backend

Is there any way to share Bluetooth pairing information between two slave nodes in a mesh network? For instance, if Person1 pairs a phone to Node1 and leaves the scannable area. Sometime later, when Person1 enters Node2's scannable area, can the pairing information be used to connect directly to Person1 again? Without needing to reconnect manually, share a PIN, and complete all other steps.

We can assume that Node1 and Node2 are on a LAN or VLAN at least and can connect directly to each other. Node1 and Node2 can overlap in scanning area if necessary, but the question is applicable if they don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way, 
The output from the pairing process is the link key, which is used in subsequent connections.
The Link key is a function of the Bluetooth device address. Since Node 1 and 2 would have different Bluetooth Device Address , this key will be different even if the same pin is used.

So the only way is to share the PIN and re-do the pairing process,
Note paring process is only one time , devices can store some fixed number of generated link keys. 
If you share the PIN securely then you can also consider the devices doing automatic paring programmatically without interrupting the user.

If you use latest Bluetooth (2.1 and above) with Simple paring modes you can consider just-works paring process which would not prompt for any PIN/input from the user.